# What am I doing wrong? Deriving

Tags: derivatives, mathematical-modeling

I'm doing the same problem as the one on pg. 5 of this link: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~pwn/01~ch1_solutions.pdf

I got the same answer for my equation, although my approach was slightly different. I have the formula for cost in terms of the crew workers, but when I derive, I don't get the same result. Am I doing something wrong?
This is my equation for cost:

$C=500 \frac{280}{k+1}+(18000+800 \frac{280}{k+1})(k)$

So,

$\frac{dC}{dn}= -\frac{140000}{(k+1)^2}+18000+\frac{224000}{(k+2)^2}$

Is that correct?

Comment: Is that last $k$ a multiplication?  Have you canceled it with the $k+1$ portion of $800\frac{280}{k+1}$ (with a little algebra)?

Comment: @abiessu No I haven't, but will that change the outcome? Whenever I try to derive it, I get stuck with a negative and can't get a solution (when setting the derivative equal to zero)

Comment: If my derivative estimator is working, you will have gotten a derivative of the form $C'=-{A\over (k+1)^2}+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants arising from the aforementioned algebra.  Then $C'=0$ exactly when ${A\over (k+1)^2}=B$.  Is that similar to the outcome you got?

Comment: @abiessu Oh wow, I completely forgot the negative in the front. Now I got it, thanks!

Comment: @abiessu Sorry, but can you take a look at my edit in my original post? I just wanted to make sure I did it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the referenced page has two formulas, one for $k \lt 19$ and one for $k \ge 19$.  The first one you have derived correctly (except for the $k+2$ term on the end, which should be $k+1$).  The second is as follows:

$$C={500\cdot 280\over k+1}+18000k+{800\cdot 280\cdot k\over k+1}+{10000\cdot 280\over k+1}-140000$$

$$\iff C=18000k+800\cdot 280+{9700\cdot 280\over k+1}-140000$$

Then,

$${dC\over dk}=-{9700\cdot 280\over (k+1)^2}+18000$$

Since the first equation has an always-positive derivative, it is increasing for all $k$, and therefore it is minimized when $k$ takes on the smallest value within its allowed range ($k=19$).  The second equation has the possibility of a zero-valued derivative within the allowed range for $k$, which will occur at

$$18000(k+1)^2=9700\cdot 280$$

or

$$k=\sqrt{9700\cdot 280\over 18000}-1$$

And this value, if it is within the range allowed for $k$ for this formula ($0 \le k\lt 19$), will be the minimum value for that portion.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the original equation, it's the same as the on in the link, yet somehow they had a solution...

Comment: I see the problem, we need to apply all the parenthesis that they have, and use both portions of the equation ($k \le 19$ vs. $k \gt 19$).

Comment: $500 \frac{280}{x+1} +(18,000 + 800 \frac{280}{x+1}) x$

Comment: ^^ That is what they had

Comment: I understand, please see my updated answer.